# AWK or grep with cut. Need help cutting a field

Tags: awk, grep, cut

I have this file and need to cut field 3 which should be cut - f 3. Right? I am using this code and its absolutely not doing anything for me.

grep '^2014-' FileName | cut - f 3| less

[image]

Comment: So what does this command return?

Comment: [Do not post text as images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Apart from the space in `-f`, `cut` assumes tab-delimited fields by default. Is that what you have?

Answer (score 2):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can do what grep and cut do, and awk is more flexible by default than cut about its field separators

```bash
awk '/^2014-/ {print $3}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you have a whitespace after `-` and before `f`:

```
grep '^2014-' FileName | cut - f 3| less
                              ^ here
```

It should be:

```
grep '^2014-' FileName | cut -f 3 | less
```